# Search function incomplete

Tags: php, mysql

I am implementing a search function on a web site.

There is a field called nombre_ciudad and a value for this field is "Ciudad Juárez".

I need to search for the term "Ju" and now it doesn't work.

This is the part of the code that I am using now:

```
$sql.=" OR nombre_ciudad LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
```

The search works for terms like "Ciudad Juarez", "C", "ciudad", but not for "arez" or "rez"

Comment: So add `%` in the beginning of search term.

Comment: You need to add `%` in the beginning as well: `like '%...`

Comment: The documentation has an explanation of what the different wildcard characters represent. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you are missing the wildcard character `%` at the start of the pattern
2. you are vulnerable to SQL injection, see: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

The `%` symbol in MySQL acts as a wildcard.  If I'm trying to search for `ciudad`, and I type in `LIKE '"da%"'`, I would get back all entries that start with `da`, and have any ending after that, including `dad`.  In order to search *before* and *after* your query, you need to place a wildcard before and after, like this:

```
OR nombre_ciudad LIKE '%da%';
```